# Distance from a point to a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The distance $D(x,B)$ from a point $x$ to a nonempty subset $B$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is defined to be

$$ D(x,B) = \inf_{b \in B} d(x,b) $$

Show that for any $x,y \in X$, then $$ | D(x,B) - D(y,B) | \leq d(x,y) $$

My attempt:

Since $d$ is a metric then

$$ d(x,b) \leq d(x,y) + d(y, b) \implies d(x,b) - d(x,y) \leq d(y,b)$$

Hence, $d(x,b) - d(x,y)$ is a lower bound for $\{ d(y,b) : b \in B\} $ Hence, we must have

$$ d(x,b) - d(x,y) \leq D(y,B) \implies d(x,b) \leq D(y,B) + d(x,y) \implies D(x,B) \leq D(y,b) + d(x,y) \implies D(x,B) - D(y,B) \leq d(x,y)$$

Similarly, we obtain $D(x,B) - D(y,B) \geq - d(x,y) $. The result now follows.

Is this a correct approach? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Your sentence "Hence $d(x, b) - d(x, y)$ is a lower bound for..." is wrong.

Comment: should I fix this $b$ ?

Comment: You have $\forall b, d(x, b) - d(x, y) \le d(y, b)$. Now let $b_n$ be a sequence s.t. $d(y, b_n) \to D(y, B)$. If $b_n$ converges to $b_\infty$, then the only thing you have is $d(x, b_\infty) - d(x, y) \le D(y, B)$.

Comment: To correct this, you can say that $D(x, B) \le d(x, b)$ thus you have $D(x, B) - d(x, y) \le d(y, b)$ and only after you can take infimum, obtaining what you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b$ in $B$, then $D(x,B)\leqslant d(x,b)$ by definition of $D(x,B)$ and $d(x,b)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,b)$ by the triangular inequality hence $D(x,B)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,b)$.

Taking the infimum over $b$ in $B$ of the RHS, one gets $D(x,B)\leqslant d(x,y)+\inf\limits_{b\in B}d(y,b)$, that is, $D(x,B)\leqslant d(x,y)+D(y,B)$.

Exchanging $x$ and $y$ yields $D(y,B)\leqslant d(x,y)+D(x,B)$ because $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

For all $z\in B$ one has
$$D(x,B)\leq d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ .$$
This says that $D(x,B)-d(x,y)$ is a lower bound for $\{d(y,z)\>|\>z\in B\}$. From this we conclude that $D(x,B)-d(x,y)\leq D(y,B)$, and using symmetry we can infer the claim.